# Using standalone 'gsutil' from within GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts, gsutil

I'm trying to use the standalone `gsutil` tool from within a container running in a GKE cluster, but I cannot get it to work. I believe the cluster has adequate permissions (see below). However, running

```
./gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/
```

yields

```
ServiceException: 401 Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket my-bucket.
```

Am I missing anything? I don't have a `.boto` file, as I believe it shouldn't be necessary—or is it? This is the list of scopes that the cluster and the node pool have:

```
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Yes, you'll need *some* sort of boto file.

**Long answer:**
Generally, for GCE instances, you don't need a `~/.boto` file because the `/etc/boto.cfg` file is already present -- the Boto library that GSUtil uses knows to look for this by default.  On Debian images, it contains these lines:

```
# This file is automatically created at boot time by the /usr/lib/python
# 2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/boto/boto_config.pyc script.
# Do not edit this file directly. If you need to add items to this file,
# create or edit /etc/boto.cfg.template instead and then re-run the
# script.

[GSUtil]
default_project_id = <PROJECT NUMBER HERE>
default_api_version = 2

[GoogleCompute]
service_account = default

[Plugin]
plugin_directory = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/boto
```

If you want to mimic this behavior on your GKE container, you'll have to have the `google-compute-engine` python package installed, along with a having a boto file that tells gsutil to load that plugin from where ever it was installed to, as seen above. On GCE (and I'm assuming GKE as well, although I've not tested it), this plugin allows a VM to talk to its metadata server to obtain credentials for the specified service account.

Answer (score 7):

You can use gsutil inside a docker container on GKE with a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account), or with your own credentials.

**Service Account**

**1)** Add the `service-account.json` file to your project.

**2)** Add a `.boto` file to your project pointing to the `service-account.json` file:

```
[Credentials]
gs_service_key_file = /path/to/service-account.json
```

**3)** In your Dockerfile, set the `BOTO_CONFIG` environment variable to point to this `.boto` file:

```
ENV BOTO_CONFIG=/path/to/.boto
```

**Own Credentials**

**1)** Locally, run gcloud auth login. A `.boto` file will be created at *~/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/your@account.com/.boto* with the following structure:

```
[OAuth2]
client_id = <id>.apps.googleusercontent.com
client_secret = <secret>

[Credentials]
gs_oauth2_refresh_token = <token>
```

**2)** Copy this `.boto` file into your project

**3)** In your Dockerfile, set the `BOTO_CONFIG` environment variable to point to this `.boto` file:

```
ENV BOTO_CONFIG=/path/to/.boto
```

*I installed standalone gsutil in the docker container using pip install gsutil*